# Exceptions to the rule that AAVE can omit "is" and "are" iff the corresponding form in standard English can be contracted?

Tags: american-english, contractions, african-american-vernacular-english

According to the [Wikipedia page for African-American Vernacular English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Other_grammatical_characteristics):

> - Only the forms is and are (of which the latter is anyway often replaced by is) can be omitted; am, was, and were are not deleted.
> - These forms cannot be omitted when they would be pronounced with stress in General American (whether or not the stress serves
>     specifically to impart an emphatic sense to the verb's meaning).
> - These forms cannot be omitted when the corresponding form in standard English cannot show contraction (and vice versa). For
>     example, I don't know where he is cannot be reduced to *I don't know
>     where he just as in standard English forms the corresponding reduction
>     *I don't know where he's is likewise impossible. (I don't know where he at is possible, paralleling I don't know where he's at in standard
>     English.)

Are there any exceptions to this rule?